# Set A minus Set B

Tags: c#, .net, set

I am trying to take away one set from another in the most efficient way. So if I have the following sets A and B then A_minus_B should give {1, 2, 6}. Here is what I have although I am sure it is not the most efficient way.

```
HashSet<int> A = new HashSet<int>{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
HashSet<int> B = new HashSet<int> { 3, 4, 5 };

HashSet<int> A_minus_B = new HashSet<int>(A);

foreach(int n in A){
    if(B.Contains(n)) A_minus_B.Remove(n);
}
```

Comment: Take a look at the `Except` extension method in LINQ.  You can select all items from one list where they don't exist in another list.

Comment: Have you looked at [ExceptWith](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299875.aspx)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the `Except()` method. Here is the code:

```
HashSet<int> A_minus_B = new HashSet<int>(A.Except(B));
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this :

```
var setA= new HashSet<int>();
var setB= new HashSet<int>();
...

var remaining = new HashSet<int>(setA);
remaining.ExceptWith(setB);
```

`remaining` is your new filtered set.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ExceptWith](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299875.aspx), it will modify `A` by removing items which are in `B`:

```
A.ExceptWith(B);
```

You can also use `Except` which will return new set;

Comment: Note that this is modifying the set `A`, not returning a new set that represents the set difference.

Comment: Thanks, I've modified my answer to expose it.